# Why cant I chain after std::ranges::views::join?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I recently discovered the ranges stdandard library and encountered a strange behavior. When chaining multiple range adaptors, I can't chain after using `std::ranges::views::join`:

`vec | std::ranges::views::slide(2) | std::ranges::views::join`

works as intended, but

`vec | std::ranges::views::slide(2) | std::ranges::views::join | std::ranges::views::slide(2)`

will result in compilation error:

```
error: no match for 'operator|' (operand types are 'std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::slide_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int> > > >' and 'std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Slide, int>')
  265 |   vec | std::ranges::views::slide(2) | std::ranges::views::join | std::ranges::views::slide(2);
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      |                                                     |
      |                                      |                                                     std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Slide, int>
      |                                      std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::slide_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int> > > >
```

Why is that? and what do I have to do to make multiple joins work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful.  I was able to get having two slides work, but I had to use an interim value.  Probably a better way.  But I had to guess what your omitted code is doing.

Comment: FYI, `std::ranges::views::meow` can be simply written as `std::views::meow`. `std::views` is a namespace alias for `std::ranges::views`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`slide_view` requires `forward_range` since the elements need to be traversed more than once.

This is not the case for `join_view` in your case, because the latter joins a nested range whose elements are prvalue ranges (`slide_view` acts on `vector` will produce a range whose element type is prvalue `span` as "window"), which makes it just an `input_range`.

The constraints are not satisfied so compilation fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot! To make it a forward_range I can do the following: ```vec | std::ranges::views::slide(2) | std::ranges::views::join | std::ranges::to<std::vector<int>>() | std::ranges::views::slide(2)```. Or is there a better way?